# Status bar is not displaying in mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer, ios7-statusbar

I have problem with status bar. Its is displaying as usual in other views but when i try to send mail using mfmailcomposeviewcontroller it get disappear.

I have tried all ways but did not put any effect.

I have tried

1. ```
   [self presentViewController:MailController animated:YES completion:^{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
   }];
   ```
2. set status bar appearance in viewdidload and in button tap event of opening mail composer.

But nothing is working.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: have you add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance in plist?

Comment: but it is not working with mfmailcomposeviewcontroller